# Change php variable value with jquery

Tags: php

I have the following issue. I am building a form in which a user can select a value from a select option and i want to save that value into a php variable. The form and everything are in the same php file. Is there anyway to achieve something like that with jquery?

I do not want to submit the form, just to change the value of php variable.

Thanks

Comment: Probably this is what you're looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming) and http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: you can do this by ajax and jquery    ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is no longer running, when the user received the HTML-Form, since the request ended. Thus, there is no variable which you could set.

However, you can send a new request via jQuery.ajax() with the value of your select field. How to handle this request, depends strongly on what you want to do with the value the user provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not. You can make an ajax call to PHP, but this will load the same page again in the background. This will not use the php variable of the current loaded page.

Maybe you can provide us some sample code to have a better understanding of what you try to achieve.

Comment: OK this is what i got so far.

this is the php file
<?php 
$cmp = $_REQUEST["company"];

and i have a mysql select query based on $cmp value
?>

my script to set the value is
$("#companyid").change(function(){
$post("file.php",{company: $("#select_list :selected").val()});
});

Comment: Is this impossible even with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible without submitting the form. You can manipulate any elements thus form elements' value on a page with JS via the DOM and when the form is submitted they become PHP variables on the server-side. PHP variables can only be altered on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

*PHP* is a **server-side** language while *Javascript* is a **client-side** language only. Unless you make an **[AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)** (*[jQuery version](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)*) call or a **form submit**, your *Javascript* will never communicate with *PHP*.